# Run UserData after instance initialize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I´m using cloudformation to create an ec2 instance through an AMI which contains a docker image.

The idea is use userData to run the docker image once that the instance is initialized.

But once that I connect by ssh and check the docker containers, no docker container is running.

This is my cloudformation template

```
     "instancei0755a35a9c753812d": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
    "DisableApiTermination": "false",
    "InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior": "stop",
    "ImageId": "ami-foooo",
    "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
    "KeyName": "jenkins_price",
    "Monitoring": "false",
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "Jenkins"
      },
      {
        "Key": "Type",
        "Value": "jenkins"
      }
    ],
    "Volumes": [
      {
        "Device": "/dev/sdf",
        "VolumeId": {
          "Ref": "volumevolab668c6e"
        }
      }
    ],
    "NetworkInterfaces": [
      {
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true,
        "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
        "DeviceIndex": 0,
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "subnet"
        },
        "GroupSet": [
          {
            "Ref": "jenkinsSg"
          },
          {
            "Ref": "usersSshSg"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "UserData": {
      "Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "#!/bin/bash -v\n",
            "# Run Jenkins docker image\n",
            "cd /home/ec2-user/price_aws/images/jenkins\n",
            "docker-compose up &\n"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

As far as I know UserData should be executed once the instance is running.

I´m doing something wrong?

Regards.

Comment: Have you checked the system log to see if anything bad happened during the execution of the user-data? There's a "magic" line that will output the user-data log to a file for easy viewing: https://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-user-data-output/

Comment: Cool, I saw the log of cloud-init-output.log and gave me the information. It´s seems at that point docker-container is not yet set in my env, any suggestion?

Comment: Rewrite the script to make sure the environment gets set up before it's needed, then test with a new instance.